# Want to try out spinners using sample codes I find on the net. List doesn't show up

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to try and understand the concept of spinners in Android for our project and I have been trying out the sample spinner codes I see on the net.

My problem is the list won't show up. Only a blank spinner item can be seen.

This is what I see on my screen (My android version is 4.4.2) 
https://scontent.fmnl3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/14237654_845327692271131_7356941869782744935_n.jpg?oh=6563aa49e3cb92706f5a17d5460c5a70&oe=57CFE274

This is the code I'm trying to run:
**RequestAppointmentView.java**

```
public class RequestAppointmentView extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

Spinner spinnerDropDown;
String[] cities = {
        " ",
        "Mumbai",
        "Delhi",
        "Bangalore",
        "Hyderabad",
        "Ahmedabad",
        "Chennai",
        "Kolkata",
        "Pune",
        "Jabalpur"          
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_appointment_view);


    // Get reference of SpinnerView from layout/main_activity.xml
            spinnerDropDown =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.
                    R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item ,cities);
            spinnerDropDown.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinnerDropDown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // Get select item
                    int sid=spinnerDropDown.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected City : " + cities[sid],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                }
            });

   }

   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      // On selecting a spinner item

   }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.set_appointment_view, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**activity_set_appointment_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightcolor"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.heart.RequestAppointmentView" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/request_appointment_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Request an Appointment"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/darkcolor" />

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:scaleX="0.8"
    android:scaleY="0.8" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Spinner Dropdown"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="#ff5500"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:popupBackground="#FFFF99"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Button" />
```

I also tried one code where it uses a string-array embedded in the **values.xml**
Am I missing something?

Please nevermind the datePicker.
Also, I'm new to posting in stackoverflow, please tell me what information should I add. Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: I tried to put your code into the sample project, the empty spinner is shown because the first item is empty as the first item in your list is " ". I also see the list of the items shown after I click the spinner.

Comment: I copied again what I posted here to my IDE and edited out the " " item in my list. Still the same :( Maybe the problem is in my phone? 

Whenever I click the spinner, this shows up in my LogCat.
`09-07 07:19:36.584: D/AbsListView(27737): onDetachedFromWindow`

`09-07 07:19:36.604: W/InputEventReceiver(27737): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.`

`09-07 07:19:36.604: E/ViewRootImpl(27737): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`

Btw, this requestanappointment activity shows up when a button from a mainactivity is clicked.

Comment: I tried making the RequestAnAppointment activity into the launcher activity and the Spinner worked! I'll figure out from this hopefully. Thanks